# How do I add a space between any punctuation and tokens in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to add a space in between each punctuation symbol and token, so that the text looks something like this:

```
 " in dreams " might keep you awake at night , but not because of its creepy imagery , bizarre visual style or story about a clairvoyant madman who lures young girls to their untimely deaths . 
no , the source of potential sleeplessness here lies within the movie's brutally squandered potential , the least of which is an admittedly nifty premise - even by tired serial killer genre standards . 
the big letdown , however , comes upon the realization that this 100-minute head-scratcher was masterminded by neil jordan , the man behind " the crying game . " 
he's no stranger to cinematic weirdness , but this nutty nonsense really pushes the envelope . 
things start out strong enough , with cinematographer darius khondji's stunning camera work guiding viewers into the bowels of a underwater ghost town during a creepy prologue that establishes a notably grim tone right off the bat . 
this eerie opulence remains a dazzling display of showmanship throughout the entire film - there's even something macabre about the way khondji photographs a rustic , seemingly innocent new england autumn - but if there ever was a film that didn't deserve so good a polish , it's this one .
```

Note that the input string could be, for example, "This is a simple - straightforward P.H.P. Program! Isn't it?"

The output should be: " This is a simple - straightforward P . H . P . Program ! Isn ' t it ? "

Punctuation characters in this case are anything that is not a letter or a number.

Comment: What do you consider a token?

Comment: What is the input string ?

Comment: What are punctuation character for you?

Comment: A token is an alphanumeric string in this case. The input string is any sequence of words and punctuation. Punctuation characters are anything that is not a letter or a number.

Comment: Why the last `?"` got expanded? This isn't followed by a letter.

Comment: It doesn't have to be followed by a letter. For example, a space is created in between "!!", and this would become " ! ! ". So a space is needed between tokens, between punctuation and tokens, and also between punctuation symbols themselves. I hope that helps.

Comment: Are spaces considered punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use "hungry" regular expression engine in your case, simple string replace will do the job:

```
<?php
$input_string = "bla bla,bla.another bla;";
//you can extend this array as you wish
$punctoations = array(".",",",":",";");  
//your replacements, same order as above array    
$replacements = array (" . "," , "," : "," ; "); 
echo str_replace($punctoations, $replacements, $input_string);
?>
```

See how more info in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).